# What is the best practice to use expectations on mocked objects in controllers

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I often want to mock out a Component or Object in a controller. I use the controllerSpy method to do that like this:

```
public function controllerSpy($event, $controller = null)
{
    parent::controllerSpy($event, $controller);

    $OrderConfirmation = $this->getMockBuilder('OrderConfirmation')
        ->setMethods(['send'])
        ->getMock();
    $OrderConfirmation->expects($this->once())->method('send');
    $this->_controller->OrderConfirmation = $OrderConfirmation;
}
```

The Problem is that the expectation that the send-Method is called is set in every test. But it depends on the scenario, there are scenarios where the confirmation shall not be sent. I would like to configure the expectation in the test itself and not globally in the `controllerSpy` method. Something like this:

```
public function testAddOrder()
{
    $this->_controller->OrderConfirmation->expects($this->once())->method('send');
    $this->post('/add_order');
}
```

But the problem her is that the expectation will be lost, since the whole OrderConfirmation object is overwritten later. Has anybody solved this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just listen to the `Controller.initialize` event, that's what the test dispatcher does too:

```php
public function testAddOrder()
{
    \Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(
        'Controller.initialize',
        function (\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
            /** @var \Cake\Controller\Controller $controller */
            $controller = $event->getSubject();
            
            // ...

            $controller->OrderConfirmation = $OrderConfirmation;
        }
    );

    $this->post('/add_order');
}
```

Or implement for example a callback for the `controllerSpy()` method, something like this:

```php
protected $controllerSpyCallback;

public function controllerSpy($event, $controller = null)
{
    parent::controllerSpy($event, $controller);

    if (is_callable($this->controllerSpyCallback)) {
        $this->controllerSpyCallback($this->_controller);
    }
}

public function testAddOrder()
{
    $this->controllerSpyCallback = function (\Cake\Controller\Controller $controller) {
        // ...
        
        $controller->OrderConfirmation = $OrderConfirmation;
    };

    $this->post('/add_order');
}
```